# Jquery positioning code and recalling it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

So I have this bundle of jquery code (Note some of it is probably extremely wrong but working) and there are a few areas where I would like to recall functions but I am having difficulties doing so. The code is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#myTablePager").html("");
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",      
       url: "fetchTable.php",
      data: { ticketType:  $("#selectType option:selected").val()}  
    }).done(function( msg ) { 

            $("#troubleTable").html(msg); 
            $('#myTable').pageMe({pagerSelector:'#myTablePager',showPrevNext:true,hidePageNumbers:false,perPage:10});
    });


});
$(function (){ 
   $("#selectType").change(function (){ 
    $("#myTablePager").html("");
    $.ajax({  
       type: "POST",      
       url: "fetchTable.php", 
      data: { ticketType:  $("#selectType option:selected").val()} 
    }).done(function( msg ) {
            $("#troubleTable").html(msg); 
            $('#myTable').pageMe({pagerSelector:'#myTablePager',showPrevNext:true,hidePageNumbers:false,perPage:10});
    });
   });
});
$(document).on('click', '.viewTD', function(){
   var tid = $(this).closest('tr').find('.tidTD input').val();
   $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
        url: 'modalInfo.php',
       data: 'tid=' +tid,
       success: function(d){
           $('.modal-body').html(d);
           $('.modal-title').html("Ticket ID: " + tid);
           $('#myModal').modal('show');
           var time = $('#time').val();
           var desc = $('#description').val();

           $('#Resolved').click(function(){  //Here #1
              $.ajax({type: 'post',url: 'resolveTicket.php',data: 'tid=' +tid, success: function(s){
                $('#resolvedTicket').html("Resolved");
              }});
           });

           $("#addComment").click(function(){
           $.ajax({type: 'post', data: { myData: $('#commentAdd').serialize() }, url: "addComment.php", success: function(info){
             $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'modalInfo.php',
                data: 'tid=' +tid,
                success: function(d){
                    $('.modal-body').html(d);
                    $('.modal-title').html("Ticket ID: " + tid);
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                }});
           }});
           });
       }

   });
});
```

What I am trying to do is to call above jquery to rerun from a success function in one of the ajax calls. An example of what I am trying to understand is where I have put the comment `Here 1` where I am running some Ajax command to change a row in the database to have new information passed to it VIA ajax, when that ajax call comes back as successful what I would like to do is rerun the first ajax call nested in the `$(document).ready()` function so that the first table generated when the document is loaded regenerates with fixed information.

An additional problem on this same topic is below that ajax call I have my modal ajax which is nested within the `$(document).on('click', '.viewTD'...` and the problem I am having is that when I open the modal and fill out a form within that modal (this form is generated by the ajax that is called when the modal is first opened, the `$("#myModal").modal('show')...` area to be specfic) but after doing so the ajax call doesn't ever run unless I nest the ajax within the modal jquery area that starts with the `$(document).on('click', '.viewTD'...`. The problem with doing this is that to return the fixed table I had to paste in the same jquery that is first run when the modal is opened into the success of that form's ajax call. This part is "working" albeit very broken solution in my mind because I can't add a second comment without closing and reopening the modal. I THINK I could fix this if I could recall a previous bit of jquery without just having to paste in in which is what I Was trying to do above. Any idea how I can accomplish this.

The clearest I can write it is how would I tell jquery to rerun in the success block of an ajax call.

Sorry for the unclear explanation the first time.

Comment: I'm sure there must be a question in here somewhere.

Comment: Please be more specific on what your question is, as it is very broad and unclear at the moment. Include less code with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Please read [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, I tried to clear things up and removed some of the code (left the JS) because I felt it probably wasn't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem, you can define functions and reuse.

```
function hereOne(tid) {
    $.ajax({type: 'post',url: 'resolveTicket.php',data: 'tid=' +tid, success: function(s){
        $('#resolvedTicket').html("Resolved");
    }});
}

$('#Resolved').click(hereOne(tid));
```

That's what you are trying to do?

Comment: That is what I was hoping I could do but I couldn't ever figure out of that would quite work, I found a few sources that used functions but they all were very vague solutions and I wanted to make sure I could use a function applicable to this project. Thank you Felippe, I will be trying it out shortly!